# How to set JDK version in gradle.properties in cygwin

Tags: java, gradle, cygwin

I need to run gradle build for one specific with JDK7 on windows in cygwin. In system properties JDK6 is set. And it should be used for building other projects.

I've tried to set in `gradle.properties`

```
org.gradle.java.home=/d/Java/jdk1.7.0_67/bin

/cygpath is mapped on /
```

but I get

```
Java home supplied via 'org.gradle.java.home' is invalid. Invalid directory: /d/Java/jdk1.7.0_67/bin
```

Also I've tried

```
d:\\Java\\jdk1.7.0_67\\bin\\
```

but get almost the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java home is the directory above the `bin` directory.

Comment: Thanks, The correct variant is org.gradle.java.home=d:\\Java\\jdk1.7.0_67

I tried to use /d/Java/jdk1.7.0_67, but forgot about d:\\Java\\jdk1.7.0_67